# iOS7 Background fetch beyond max permitted time

Tags: ios7, background, fetch

I'm using background fetch to periodically refresh my app content in background and sometimes it happens that I need more than 30 seconds (the max background fetch permitted time) to complete the update.

My experience is that the app gets killed by iOS watchdog and background fetch gets never called again until I reopen the app in foreground and put it in background again (https://devforums.apple.com/thread/223357, login required). For this reason I added a timer to get notified when the background time is about to end so that I can call the background fetch completion handler and avoid being killed by the watchdog.

My question is: is it acceptable to simply call the completion handler even if the operations the app was carrying on were not completed?

My understanding is that calling the completion handler puts the app in the suspended state and my running threads are frozen and resumed on the next background fetch. Am I allowed to do this or I should terminate all my running threads before calling the completion handler?

Thanks in advance